Compare value in Pandas DataFrame with the value in the row before for each column
I have a DataFrame that contains several columns (44) with the information whether buttons have been pressed or not, represented by 4 states. I am trying to get the information in which row it was pressed. Maybe there is a performant solution. The data frame has a length of almost 4 million rows.
Example:



Button 1
Button 2
Button 3




0
1
2


0
1
0


0
0
2


1
0
0


0
1
0



A button is pressed when the value changes from zero to one:



Button 1
Button 2
Button 3



















pressed





pressed




I tried it with apply and this function:
def if_pressed(new, old):
            if new == 1 and old == 0:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0

This is not working as shift() and apply are not working together. With apply I cannot switch the row:
columns = list(df)

for c in columns:
    df[c + '_comp'] = df.apply(lambda row:if_pressed(row[c], row[c].shift()), 
                               axis=1)

I also tried to copy and shift the data frame. Here it was only possible for me to find different cells, but not to check the difference between them.

You can create a boolean mask comparing the rows with (df == df.shift() + 1) to ensure that a change of 1 unit occurred and (df == 1) to ensure the change was from 0 to 1 (and not from 1 to 2, for example).
Then use the mask to replace the True values with "pressed" and the False values with "".
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Button 1": [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        "Button 2": [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        "Button 3": [2, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    }
)

pressed = (df == df.shift() + 1) & (df == 1)
df[pressed] = "pressed"
df[~pressed] = ""

  Button 1 Button 2 Button 3
0                           
1                           
2                           
3  pressed                  
4           pressed   


Code
cond = df.shift().eq(0) & df.eq(1)
out = df.mask(cond, 'pressed').mask(~cond, '')

out:
   Button 1 Button 2 Button 3
0                           
1                           
2                           
3  pressed                  
4           pressed         

